# Error implementing Support Library Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library

I'm trying to implement the new v7 Support Library `ActionBar`. However, I can't get it to run properly.

Here's the exception

```
07-25 09:30:01.704: E/AndroidRuntime(9175): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-25 09:30:01.704: E/AndroidRuntime(9175): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable
07-25 09:30:01.704: E/AndroidRuntime(9175):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:98)
07-25 09:30:01.704: E/AndroidRuntime(9175):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:58)
07-25 09:30:01.704: E/AndroidRuntime(9175):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
07-25 09:30:01.704: E/AndroidRuntime(9175):     at com.cidaut.termoweb.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
07-25 09:30:01.704: E/AndroidRuntime(9175):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
07-25 09:30:01.704: E/AndroidRuntime(9175):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-25 09:30:01.704: E/AndroidRuntime(9175):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
07-25 09:30:01.704: E/AndroidRuntime(9175):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
07-25 09:30:01.704: E/AndroidRuntime(9175):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-25 09:30:01.704: E/AndroidRuntime(9175):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
07-25 09:30:01.704: E/AndroidRuntime(9175):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-25 09:30:01.704: E/AndroidRuntime(9175):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-25 09:30:01.704: E/AndroidRuntime(9175):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
07-25 09:30:01.704: E/AndroidRuntime(9175):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-25 09:30:01.704: E/AndroidRuntime(9175):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-25 09:30:01.704: E/AndroidRuntime(9175):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
07-25 09:30:01.704: E/AndroidRuntime(9175):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-25 09:30:01.704: E/AndroidRuntime(9175):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The problem happens at the `super.onCreate(bundle)` call at `onCreate()`.

Here's all my theming related XML:

styled.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>
    <style name="Theme.Termoweb" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_termoweb</item>
        <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Termoweb</item>
        <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Termoweb</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Termoweb</item>
        <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Termoweb</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Termoweb</item>
        <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_termoweb</item>
        <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_termoweb</item>
        <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Termoweb</item>
        <!-- Light.DarkActionBar specific -->
        <item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.Termoweb.Widget</item>
    </style>



    <style name="ActionBar.Solid.Termoweb" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_termoweb</item>
        <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_termoweb</item>
        <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_termoweb</item>
        <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Termoweb</item>
    </style>


    <style name="ActionBar.Transparent.Termoweb" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="background">@drawable/ab_transparent_termoweb</item>
        <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Termoweb</item>
    </style>


    <style name="PopupMenu.Termoweb" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView.Menu">
        <item name="popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_termoweb</item>
    </style>


    <style name="DropDownListView.Termoweb" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">
        <item name="listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_termoweb</item>
    </style>


    <style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Termoweb" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">
        <item name="background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_termoweb</item>
    </style>


    <style name="DropDownNav.Termoweb" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner">
        <item name="background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_termoweb</item>
        <item name="popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_termoweb</item>
        <item name="dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_termoweb</item>
    </style>


    <style name="ProgressBar.Termoweb" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
        <item name="progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_termoweb</item>
    </style>


    <style name="ActionButton.CloseMode.Termoweb" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.CloseMode">
        <item name="background">@drawable/btn_cab_done_termoweb</item>
    </style>


    <!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
    <style name="Theme.Termoweb.Widget" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Termoweb</item>
        <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Termoweb</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.cidaut.termoweb"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Termoweb" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.cidaut.termoweb.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

So, how I solved this problem:

1. Import support library as a project from "sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat".
2. Reference library in your project (for Eclipse, "Properties - Android - Add").
3. Build projects (for Eclipse, "Projects - Build All"). Make sure, you have "android.support.v7.appcompat" in your main project gen folder.
4. If it doesn't worked - clean and rebuild project.

Comment: Are you completely sure that you have "android.support.v7.appcompat.R.java" in your gen folder? Without it, it won't work

Comment: I am completely and absolutely sure I have R.java in v7 gen folder.

Comment: I had referenced `@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner` which for some reason does not exist. I just removed every reference to that style and everything worked like a charm.

Comment: Thanks. "Build ALL"... How can I miss it, yet I have.

Comment: Yeah, you must have android.support.v7.appcompat package in the gen folder.

Comment: I added the library and it shows in the `referenced folder` but can't find it in the Android tab.

Answer (score 14):

I have done the following and worked for me.

- Delete the jar from the libs folder.
- Import the sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\ project in your eclipse workspace.
- Ensure that the android-support-v4.jar is the same in your project.
- Add the appcompat as a library to your project.

Ensure that your in yout Manifest.xml your activity has the correct theme

```
    <activity
        android:name="***.*****.******"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
         >
```

Good Luck ;)

Comment: +1 for mentioning that the activity must use the "Theme.AppCompat" theme or a theme that sub classes "Theme.AppCompat"

Answer (score 4):

In addition to BoredT's answer I added this line to res/values/styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

Answer (score 2):

Follow steps from Adding libraries with resources -> Eclipse http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html :

1. follow all the steps (use copy project in workspace)
2. add  `android.library.reference.1=../android-support-v7-appcompat` to your project.properties
3. use `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"` I used it in application tag you can apply to individual activities as well

Rebuild all!

Comment: This resolved my issue. Adding the line to project.properties allowed Eclipse to generate R.java.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change your target version to 18 in the manifest.

```
android:targetSdkVersion="18"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solve the problem: rebuild the adroid-support-v7-appcompat library project in your eclipse workspace. Then build your own project again.

Answer (score 1):

How to import a project as a library in android studio? Follow the tips blog as a reference:
http://showlabor.blogspot.com.br/2013/05/actionbarsherlock-in-android-studio-01.html

The next question, also helped a lot:
[Error implementing Support Library Action Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17851783/error-implementing-support-library-action-bar)

The following image shows the structure of the imported project. That is copied to the root of my project and placed in the directory 'libraries':
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/67269258/Tuto/tree.PNG

In addition to mounting the above structure. In 'settings.glade' I had to add the new project:

```
include ':FreeMusic', ':libraries:ActionBarCompat:appcompat'
```

Inside the library project, added the file 'build.gradle'
It is located in: libraries/ActionBarCompat/appcompat

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile files(
        'libs/android-support-v4.jar',
        'libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar'
    )
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

In 'build.gradle' (internal project) of my project.

```
dependencies {
 compile project(':libraries:ActionBarCompat:appcompat')
}
```

In android manifest added the necessary theme:

```
<activity
 android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
 android:name="es.hol.soundmedia.MainActivity"
```

After all this work. Perhaps an easier way to set this up, but for me the account is working.
Unfortunately I can not show the result, because I'm being blocked, but I hope the instructions help.

Answer (score 1):

For those that don't like needing manual user effort in Eclipse in order to do a build from checkout, the magical change that Eclipse makes is to add a line to project.properties like:

```
android.library.reference.1=../android-support-v7-appcompat
```

This is enough to build your application from ant.  You can do this in the source yourself, or via the Eclipse user interface - either way you can check it in to your version control system and successfully build from a fresh checkout of the source without requiring manual steps.

But you can instead make the path a sub-directory of your own project if that suits better, E.g.

```
android.library.reference.1=android-support-v7-appcompat
```

... and ...

```
cp -r $SDK/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat android-support-v7-appcompat
```

Note that Eclipse will still show various warnings until the sub-directory is also added [manually!] to Eclipse's workspace as a project.  But an ant build will successfully build without using Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Check for R.java for appcompat v7 jar is present in your generated folders of your application