# Android Action Bar with tabs Runtime error

Tags: android

```
   package com.example.actionbar;


     // creating a simple 3 tabbed action bar
      import android.os.Bundle;
      import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
      import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
      import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
      import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab;
      import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;





          public class Main_Fragment extends ActionBarActivity {

         @Override
          protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
         {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.fragment_home);

    ActionBar actionbar=getSupportActionBar();
actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
actionbar.setTitle("Tabbed layout");

ActionBar.Tab Fragtab1=actionbar.newTab().setText("Fragment1");
ActionBar.Tab Fragtab2=actionbar.newTab().setText("Fragment2");
ActionBar.Tab Fragtab3=actionbar.newTab().setText("Fragment3");

Fragment Fragment1 =new Fragment1();
 Fragment Fragment2 =new Fragment2();
 Fragment Fragment3 =new Fragment3();

Fragtab1.setTabListener(new  MyTabListener(Fragment1));
Fragtab1.setTabListener(new  MyTabListener(Fragment2));
 Fragtab1.setTabListener(new  MyTabListener(Fragment3));

actionbar.addTab(Fragtab1);
actionbar.addTab(Fragtab2);
actionbar.addTab(Fragtab3);
      }

class MyTabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {

public Fragment fragment;   
public MyTabListener(Fragment fragment) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
this.fragment = fragment;
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

   }
   }
```

cannot figure out the run time error.. please help
and running this code triggers an force close..

below is the `LOGCAT` of the error:

```
09-30 10:28:24.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1610): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-30 10:28:24.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1610): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable
09-30 10:28:24.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:98)
09-30 10:28:24.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:58)
09-30 10:28:24.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
09-30 10:28:24.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at com.example.actionbar.Main_Fragment.onCreate(Main_Fragment.java:21)
09-30 10:28:24.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
09-30 10:28:24.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-30 10:28:24.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
09-30 10:28:24.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
09-30 10:28:24.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-30 10:28:24.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
09-30 10:28:24.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-30 10:28:24.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-30 10:28:24.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-30 10:28:24.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-30 10:28:24.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-30 10:28:24.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-30 10:28:24.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-30 10:28:24.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error implementing Support Library Action Bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17851783/error-implementing-support-library-action-bar)

Answer (score 0):

What is the code at line 21 of Main_Fragment?

```
com.example.actionbar.Main_Fragment.onCreate(Main_Fragment.java:21)
```

Also, Change:

```
Fragtab1.setTabListener(new  MyTabListener(Fragment1));
Fragtab1.setTabListener(new  MyTabListener(Fragment2));
Fragtab1.setTabListener(new  MyTabListener(Fragment3));
```

To:

```
Fragtab1.setTabListener(new  MyTabListener(Fragment1));
Fragtab2.setTabListener(new  MyTabListener(Fragment2));
Fragtab3.setTabListener(new  MyTabListener(Fragment3));
```