# extending ActionBarActivity causing error

Tags: android, android-actionbar, fragment

I have a class that were extending FragmentActivity and importing android library v4. Now that I want to implement Navigation Drawer in my activity, I'd like to extend ActionBarActivity. And since ActionBarActivity also implements FragmentActivity, I've been told that I could still use fragments in my class with ActionBarActivity.

So I start working with ActionBarActivity, first by importing the v7 library. I copied the file from

> C:\Program Files\Android Developer Tools\sdk\extras\android\support\v7

to the `libs` folder in my app folder on workspace.

Now my Eclipse detects no errors with my class extending ActionBarActivity. However when I run it, it crashes.

Here's some information found at my LogCat (I wonder if it coulp help at any point):

```
03-27 16:30:12.113: E/AndroidRuntime(8130): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-27 16:30:12.113: E/AndroidRuntime(8130): Process: com.anggrian.readee, PID: 8130
03-27 16:30:12.113: E/AndroidRuntime(8130): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable
03-27 16:30:12.113: E/AndroidRuntime(8130):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:107)
03-27 16:30:12.113: E/AndroidRuntime(8130):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:58)
03-27 16:30:12.113: E/AndroidRuntime(8130):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
03-27 16:30:12.113: E/AndroidRuntime(8130):     at com.anggrian.readee.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
03-27 16:30:12.113: E/AndroidRuntime(8130):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
03-27 16:30:12.113: E/AndroidRuntime(8130):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-27 16:30:12.113: E/AndroidRuntime(8130):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
03-27 16:30:12.113: E/AndroidRuntime(8130):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
03-27 16:30:12.113: E/AndroidRuntime(8130):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
03-27 16:30:12.113: E/AndroidRuntime(8130):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
03-27 16:30:12.113: E/AndroidRuntime(8130):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-27 16:30:12.113: E/AndroidRuntime(8130):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-27 16:30:12.113: E/AndroidRuntime(8130):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
03-27 16:30:12.113: E/AndroidRuntime(8130):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-27 16:30:12.113: E/AndroidRuntime(8130):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-27 16:30:12.113: E/AndroidRuntime(8130):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:781)
03-27 16:30:12.113: E/AndroidRuntime(8130):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-27 16:30:12.113: E/AndroidRuntime(8130):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I wonder if I could get any help, thanks!

@Raghunandan here's my styles.xml:

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.

    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.

        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

    <!-- MY OWN THEME -->
    <style name="DarkGreyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/DarkGreyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DarkGreyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#b6b6b6</item>
    </style>

    <!-- MY OWN THEME -->
    <style name="OrangeTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/OrangeActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="OrangeActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#ff6400</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

the AppTheme is not used in AndroidManifest.xml so just ignore them. I used to use @android:style/Theme.Holo.Light in my custom themes but since I already extending ActionBarActivity in my main class, LogCat indicates I need to use AppCompat Theme.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17853109/1937802

Comment: What IDE do you use?. There is no need to copy anything to libs folder.

Comment: Eclipse, otherwise what method do you recommend to import the library to the libs folder in app project folder

Comment: did u add jar file in libs folder

Comment: @Anggrian already mentioned in my post and the link has snap shots also

Comment: once remove that jar file form lib folder after that import v7 project into eclipse workspace,after that right click on your project and click on properties -->android-->and click on add at right side of window now add v7 project and click  apply next click on ok.

Comment: I really think I imported the library right, my IDE detects no error but still crashing when I run it with the same errors as my LogCat txt shows above

Comment: @Anggrian what is the theme used in manifest file??

Comment: @Anggrian you need to have AppComapt theme in manifest like `<activity android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"` and to test get rid of your custom styles

Comment: @Anggrian and do look @ https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/34bea73a6b2d6659f327272e4f482f9d86c1b592/appcompat/res/values/themes.xml if you want to customize. Your referencing problem is solved i guess and if you have a new problem post a new question and accept this answer if it helps

Comment: dear sir @Raghunandan, you deserve many thanks and a nobel prize

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable

`AppCompat` is a library project with resources. You need to reference `AppCompat` in your Android project.

You could also check this a similar one i answered before. Found it now

[No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059612/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-style-theme-appcompat-light/21059804#21059804)

You can follow the steps @ **Adding libraries with resources** in the below link

https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Donwload the support library from sdk manager

[image]

Import library project to workspace.  Can be found @

```
sdk>/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/
```

After importing

[image]

Right click on your Android Project. Goto Properties. Choose Android. Click Add and choose `AppCompact`. Click OK. You should see a green tick upon success.

After Referencing

[image]

You are done.

Comment: I followed the instructions from your link, I'm pretty sure I imported the lib the right way, and Eclipse IDE detects no error. But it crashes when I run the app

Comment: @Anggrian it can't be that you followed all steps and still end up in errors. You have not followed it properly. and use `@` to address the specific user in your comment

Comment: @Anggrian pls check the snaps shots. If you do it right it will 100% no doubt about that

Comment: as I said earlier, I already followed the instruction from your link which I think is the same as the instructions you kindly give via screenshots.

But I got this error I cannot build the project or run the app: http://imgur.com/M4xe6J9

Comment: @Anggrian no you won't get the errors. Copy the appcompat from `sdk>/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/` to your folder where androdi project is. Then import into eclipse and then reference the same.

Comment: @Anggrian do mention the steps that you followed and snap shots in your post not as a link

Comment: did copy the appcompat folder in my android app project, error still remains

Comment: you know I did use @ several times but they don't appear here, so my apologies

Comment: @Anggrian again stressing the point that if you follow all steps it will work 100%%%%. You are missing something. I linked you to docs . posted snap shots that should be enough to fix it

Comment: you know my head is full of sh1t right now I will go and have a smoke. Will be back to follow your instructions from the scratch and let you know how it goes.

Again, thanks.

Comment: after carefully following your instructions one by one, I still get this error: Description Resource Path Location Type
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Program Files\Android Developer Tools\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\bin\android-support-v7-appcompat.jar' Readee  Build path Build Path Problem @Raghunandan

Comment: @Anggrian non exisiting. I suggest you check whether the support library is downloaded. remove all the previous references and remove all the tries and try again. Good luck.

Comment: should I also remove the v4 lib that is included in my app project by default? @Raghunandan

Comment: @Anggrian no need to remove `android-support-v4.jar` even if removed can be copied from the `sdk/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar` under the sdk to the libs folder of both library project and the androd project

Comment: I did import the lib v7 and now I get a new error:
Description Resource Path Location Type
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light'. styles.xml /Readee/res/values line 23 Android AAPT Problem

@Raghunandan

Comment: @Anggrian right click on your Appcompat library goto properties goto Android check the latest android api and click ok

Comment: it's already ticked to the latest and only one I got: 4.4.2
@Raghunandan

Comment: @Anggrian can you post styles.xml in `/Readee/res/values`

Answer (score 0):

[image]Add suppor library jar using the Java Build Path

Comment: the v7 library is already under Android Private Library in Java Build Path

Comment: thanks for the pic, I ticked the lib v7 but it still gives me crash while running the app

Comment: @Anggrian follow this https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html and it will work. you could also check the link in my post

Comment: I did follow the instruction, now my IDE detects no error, but still crashing in the app with the same error as my LogCat txt shows above

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse: **File**->**Import**->**Existing Android Code into Workspace**-> **Next**. Go to **Browse** and locate the project "C:\Program Files\Android Developer Tools\sdk\extras\android\support\v7" (in your case) and import it.
Then right click on your project -> **Properties**. Go to **Android** section on top left. In the bottom window called "**Library**" click **Add** and choose the support project you've just imported.

Make sure you import the `ActionBar` from `import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity` and not from the `import android.app.ActionBar`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and tried whole bunch of things (themes, importing external appcompat jars etc).
The only one helped to me:
1) manually copy android-support-v4.jar and android-support-v7-appcompat.jar to the lib folder of the project;
2) right click on the project -> Properties -> Libraries -> Add JARs (not external jars) - > select jars from the lib folder (which we copied on step 1) -> Order and Export tap -> Uncheck old support libraries and check new, which we just added. -> OK.