# Test app immediately crashing on android device

Tags: android

I am using a Samsung Galaxy S5 to test my android app.  It is a hello world app. So what is occurring is that every time I run the app onto my device it opens the hello world app but then immediately crashes giving me this error:

```
06-14 01:45:59.356: E/AndroidRuntime(28817): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-14 01:45:59.356: E/AndroidRuntime(28817): Process: com.example.crystalball, PID: 28817
06-14 01:45:59.356: E/AndroidRuntime(28817): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable
06-14 01:45:59.356: E/AndroidRuntime(28817):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:107)
06-14 01:45:59.356: E/AndroidRuntime(28817):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:58)
06-14 01:45:59.356: E/AndroidRuntime(28817):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
06-14 01:45:59.356: E/AndroidRuntime(28817):    at com.example.crystalball.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
06-14 01:45:59.356: E/AndroidRuntime(28817):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
06-14 01:45:59.356: E/AndroidRuntime(28817):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
06-14 01:45:59.356: E/AndroidRuntime(28817):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
06-14 01:45:59.356: E/AndroidRuntime(28817):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2386)
06-14 01:45:59.356: E/AndroidRuntime(28817):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
06-14 01:45:59.356: E/AndroidRuntime(28817):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
06-14 01:45:59.356: E/AndroidRuntime(28817):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-14 01:45:59.356: E/AndroidRuntime(28817):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-14 01:45:59.356: E/AndroidRuntime(28817):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
06-14 01:45:59.356: E/AndroidRuntime(28817):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-14 01:45:59.356: E/AndroidRuntime(28817):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-14 01:45:59.356: E/AndroidRuntime(28817):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
06-14 01:45:59.356: E/AndroidRuntime(28817):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
06-14 01:45:59.356: E/AndroidRuntime(28817):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have no idea what it means so any help would be much appreciated.

FIX:
 I had to add the appcompat to the main gen file on the project. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Please post the code for `MainActivity.java` and tell us where line 18 is.

Comment: search `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable` on google and see related links like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17851783/error-implementing-support-library-action-bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main causes for this problem:

1. You have not imported the `appcompat-v7` library in your project, or
2. You don't have the correct theme in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. It should be `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"` (or `Theme.AppCompat.Light`, &c).

Answer (score 0):

Issue are clearly highlighted in the Logcat:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable 
06-14 01:45:59.356: E/AndroidRuntime(28817):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:107)
06-14 01:45:59.356: E/AndroidRuntime(28817):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:58)
06-14 01:45:59.356: E/AndroidRuntime(28817):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
06-14 01:45:59.356: E/AndroidRuntime(28817):    at com.example.crystalball.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
```

In the above the first indicates that:

1. You've not imported the appcompat-v7 to your project or You don't have the right theme in your AndroidManifest.xml file. It should be android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
2. The last line indicates that, in your MainActivity.Java line-18 has the issue.. Please either post your code

First try with #1 - that should hopefully resolve the issue.