# Android project not working after updating project to Android L

Tags: android, android-studio

I just updated my android studio project to latest SDK version and its not working. Gradle sync is successful but app crashes on launch.

Here is the crash :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.createDelegate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:47)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:96)
            at <package>.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:170)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5541)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2411)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2507)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5692)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here are the lines in my dependencies tag in build.gradle :

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
```

My build.gradle - http://pastebin.com/NvrWZfEj

Comment: show your code where this crashes

Comment: It crashes on MainActivity.java - setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); is the line

Comment: what is your theme for the activity?

Comment: "setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); is the line" -- no, it is not. You can tell that much from the stack trace. If it were `setContentView()`, then `setContentView()` would appear in the stack trace, and it does not. It *may* be `super.onCreate()`. I suggest checking out [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17851783/error-implementing-support-library-action-bar#comment26065949_17853109) from a related Stack Overflow question and answer.

Comment: Apologies its - super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Comment: @tyczj - My theme is <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">

Comment: @commonsware so you mean that I am using something in my styles.xml which doesnt exists. How do I find which component is missing?

Comment: I would start by removing all of them, so `AppBaseTheme` is empty other than its `parent`. See if your app runs. If it does not, then this isn't your problem. If your app *does* run, start putting things back in *slowly*, testing each time, until you start crashing again.

Comment: Tried that. Couldnt figure out anything :(

Comment: Try clean action on proj. Then rebuild it. Try remove and re-import, rebuild project. Show your build.gradle file content.

Comment: Tried cleaning - Here is my build.gradle http://pastebin.com/NvrWZfEj

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: @ryanPrintup which code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably not in your code but in the build aka in the compilation so here is what I did to fix error message which were misguiding after an upgrade to 5.0 version

For me same problem was gone after recompiling the project with android 5 api 21

Choose project right click than alt-enter in eclipse compile with your device current os

Comment: Hey, can you tell me how to do that in studio?

Comment: Im no expert on Studio. But generaly i think the answer and information about building can be found here https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-build.html

Answer (score 0):

Your normally get 'NoClassDefFoundError' when the Class you are using is available at compile time ; but not at runtime.

[NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)

So my guess is ; you are using the Emulator/Device (in which your application is Run), which has Android version different from Android L(the one you Compiled your code with). So believe you can either upgrade your emulator/device to Android L...or probably set the 'minSdkVersion'(in build.gradle) to resolve the InCompatibility Issues. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue. Instead of trying to fix the old project, I removed the old project and started new one and copy pasted the legacy code one functionality at a time.

Sometimes, It is simply not worth figuring out why or what.

Comment: It will be very time consuming. Any other suggestion?